# ¿Porque me salta un error al terminar de ingresar todos los datos? C#

Tags: c#, array, bucle-for

Sé que es un poco básico esto pero no entiendo porque razón me da el siguiente error:

**Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'**

**Información adicional: Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz.**

Les dejo el código a continuación:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] notas = new int[9];
        int bajas = 0;
        int altas = 0;
        int indeterminadas = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= notas.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Por favor ingrese la nota Nº" + (i+1));
            string nota = Console.ReadLine();
            notas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(nota);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= notas.Length; j++)
        {
            if (notas[j] >= 1 && notas[j] <= 7)
            {
                bajas++;
            } else if (notas[j] >= 8 && notas[j] <= 12)
            {
                altas++;
            }else
            {
                indeterminadas++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(bajas+" alumnos tienen notas bajas.");
        Console.WriteLine(altas + " alumnos tienen notas altas.");
        Console.WriteLine(indeterminadas + " notas están escritas incorrectamente.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en esta línea `for (int i = 0; i <= notas.Length; i++)`. Le estas diciendo que entre al ciclo siempre que la variable *i* sea menor o igual al largo del arreglo. Recuerda que los arreglos comienzan desde 0.

Modifica a esto

```
for (int i = 0; i < notas.Length; i++)
```

y se solucionará :)